# How to collect coverage with jest in universal React / React Native project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, expo

We are using cross-platform implementations for our react as well as react-native components. 
In general we have the following structure:

```
src
├── component1
│   ├── index.tsx
│   └── index.spec.tsx
├── component2
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── index.native.tsx
│   ├── index.native.spec.tsx
│   ├── index.web.spec.tsx
```

We run two different test suites for native and web. On web coverage is collected from all typescript files that do not contain .native extension. But how can I configure jest to exclude `index.tsx` files from native coverage whenever an `index.native.tsx` file exists?

Do I have to manually exclude each of these files by using the `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` option or is there a way to do this with `testMatch`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any answer on this one by now?